# Form validation message in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem with validation.
I wanted show text'fill the field' after every wrong fill input on submit. And I have a problem with validation email I dont have any idea how I should do this.

**JS**

```
function onclickHandler() {
    var form = document.querySelector("#myForm"),
        fields = form.querySelectorAll(".requiredField"),
        error = form.querySelector(".error");

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var field = fields[i];
        if (field.value == "") {
            error.innerHTML = '<p>Fill this field</p>';
        } else {
            console.log('ok');
            error.remove();
        }    
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-contact">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name*" > 
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name*"> 
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address*" class="email"> 
        <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and html
        <div class="form-contact">
          <div class="item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name*" >
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name*">
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address*" class="email">
            <div class="error"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: Add this code to your question using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47896323/edit) button under your post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the process of checking for empty boxes, use the HTML boolean attribute required.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" required/>
```

That will make sure the user cannot submit until all required marked input fields are filled out.

Also, to validate an email, there is an input type for that too.

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="email"/>
```

For more info on the email input type, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email.

Hope this was helpful to you.